# array and conditional recursive types for a rest parameter in typescript 4.1

Tags: typescript

I was wanting to use conditional types for a rest parameter but I was surprised when I did a test first

Here is a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbAArMcAzgHgyggQgDsATXKZMkAbQF0A+KAXgCgpuoiThyVKPQCWZAGYREUABIAaKADplYydICqjLj24B+YQHIQEagHdkIA1p3cAXIbIB7KOctaOHMQMTi00AIJQAN7aFCaoiCJgwCKOZPa4SGIA5gDc2mgxcfYAFACU7KwhNlC4FglJZGnaOiLAFZFV6dwAvuktHqCQUACK7LAIKOhYOAT0AIxyAExyAMwsUAD0i4bGuFpd0ERsA0iZI3j4-kzMqUsr9AZOLhZWneDQAEr98HvD2If0QTrLqyY3blC4Ui0Vi8VKlWq3EyYNyBTYRRqPDKIAaKWaNjqaKa2jaHBaLHSHiAA) and here is the code:

```js
type ExtractParts<P extends any[]> =
    P extends [infer H, ...infer U]
      ? ['yes way']
      : ['no way']


interface A {
  description: string;
  action: () => {
      say: string;
      it: string;
  };
}

type Q = ExtractParts<[1,2,3]> // ['yes]
type P = ExtractParts<A[]>; // ['no way']

type R = ExtractParts<[{    // ['yes way']
  description: string;
  action: () => {
      say: string;
      it: string;
  };
}]>;
```

I was surprised by this behaviour

```js
type P = ExtractParts<A[]>; // ['no way']
```

But this works as I think because it is a strict tuple

```js
type R = ExtractParts<[{    // ['yes way']
  description: string;
  action: () => {
      say: string;
      it: string;
  };
}]>;
```

I wanted to use this technique with a rest parameter

```js
type ExtractParts<P extends any[]> =
    P extends [infer H, ...infer U]
      ? ['yes way']
      : ['no way']


function parts<P extends any[]>(...parts: ExtractParts<P>){}

const b = parts(1,2,3);
```

But `P extends [infer H, ...infer U]` returns false

Can I use conditional types like this to infer the head and tail for rest parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that an array can have 0 elements, while the tuple `[H, ...T]` must have at least one element. You can define a tuple with an optional first element, `[H?, ...T]` and that will be a base type for an array.

So in a conditional type you would use `[(infer H)?, ...infer U]`

```
type ExtractParts<P extends any[]> =
    P extends [(infer H)?, ...infer U]
      ? ['yes way']
      : ['no way']


interface A {
  description: string;
  action: () => {
      say: string;
      it: string;
  };
}


type Q = ExtractParts<[1,2,3]> // ['yes way']
type P = ExtractParts<A[]>; // ['yes way']
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsATgQwMbAArMcAzgHgyggQgDsATXKZMkAbQF0A+KAXgCgpuoiThyVKPQAUASzIAzCIigAJAJQB+ADRQAdJonTZAVUZce3JcIDkICNQDuyEKYNHuALjNkA9lBt2DHDhIGIkmjQAIJQAN6GFJaoiGJgwGJuZC64SBIA5gDchmiJyS4iCuyskY5QuLap6WTZhkZiwNVxtTncAL457b4coJBQAIrssAgo6Fg4BPQAjCoATCoAzCxQAPSrZhbWtva94NBEbCNIeRN4+CFMzFlrG-Tmlp47BkA)